# Problem switching in new dome lights in the front

Tags: electrical, lights, installation, modification

I'm trying to install these multi-color dome lights, I successfully installed the right side, but when I tried to install on the left side, the left one won't work. The product is not the issue, I tested it and the product works. When I install the original dome light, that works fine. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these LED's?  and...what is the make/model/year of your car?  You might have a BCM (body control module) or some other component that doesn't like the wattage.....or....

Comment: ... or if they're LEDs and have positive/negative reversed. (and not reversed when you tested it.)

Comment: These are LED dome lights, I checked by switching sides, it wasn't the problem. I have one dome light installed on one side, it's just the driver side one that doesn't work. The car is 2012 Ford Taurus.